# What is the max level for your Kingdom?

Tags: super-mario-run

What is the maximum level you can reach in Super Mario Run for your castle? I've read that one user had 3000 Toads and reached Level 18.

What is the maximum? And what are all the Toads you need for each level?

Comment: What I can confirm is that the maximum level is 20. I will post an answer if I get the information on the number of Toads needed for each level.

Comment: Level 9: 1000, Level 10: 1200, Level 11: 1400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toad requirements for each level are broken down like so (thank to @Jacob Krall for the first few):

- Level 9: 1000
- Level 10: 1200
- Level 11: 1400
- Level 12: 1600
- Level 13: 1800
- Level 14: 2000
- Level 15: 2200
- Level 16: 2400
- Level 17: 2600
- Level 18: 2800
- Level 19: 3000
- Level 20: 4000

Level 20 is the last level, as you can see below:

[image: Highest level kingdom in Super Mario Run]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You have to have 4000 toads to reach the highest level castle and the highest castle level is 20!

Answer (score 0):

The Max level is 20.  You need 4000 toads to do this.

Comment: Maybe you could add a source or screenshot?

Comment: WTF?! I added the needed screenshot and it was rejected...?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is mine! I got all the special coins too which unlocked secret levels. Still haven't beaten the black tube :(